# GsonConverter is not resolved

Tags: java, android, gradle, gson, retrofit

I added this in my `build.gradle` file.

**build.gradle**

```
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4
```

But still GsonConverter for retrofit2 is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey even i faced the same problem, adding the below line is not working.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

Then i went to maven repository downloaded the jar and pasted in the libs folder in android studio. the link is provided below:

```
[https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22converter-gson%22][1]
```

then added the below lines to the gradle

```
compile files('libs/converter-gson-2.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: I downloaded converter-gson-2.1.0-sources.jar, but still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

you have to also add `gson` in gradle dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0' 
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2' // this should also be there
```

And create retrofit instance like this:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.example.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: i have added : compile 'com.google-code.gson:gson:2.5' but stil not working

Comment: can you post, how are you creating retrofit instance?

Comment: anyway, can you post it? and also post `build.gradle` file.

Comment: add `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107943/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-arps).

Comment: I am creating retrofit instance as -
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com")
                .addConverterFactory(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build(); - but getting error "cannot resolve symbol GsonConverter"

Comment: using the same dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a stable version?

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```